# How to change Jquery ui button to be selected when the underlying radio is checked through code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use Jquery UI button plugin for my radio button group. The UI looks cool but the problem is when I change the underlying radio button's checked property the UI does not change. for ex. If I have 3 radio buttons say radio1, radio2, radio3 and if I make radio1 to be selected then the button does not change but when I refresh it is displaying correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {      
        $("#radio").buttonset();        
        $("#mybutton").button();
        $("#mybutton").click(function(){$("#radio1").attr("checked","checked");alert($("#radio1").attr("checked"));//returns true});
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        #format { margin-top: 2em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo">

    <form>
        <div id="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click me"/>
    </form>

</div><!-- End demo -->

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Raja

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`refresh` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-refresh) to update the state, like this:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    $("#radio1").attr("checked","checked");
    $("#radio").buttonset('refresh');
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4AJKX/), from the docs:

> **`refresh`** - Refreshes the visual state of the button. Useful for updating button state after the native element's checked or disabled state is changed programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I ran into a similar issue and using button('refresh') and buttonset('refresh') was not working. My code was contained in a bind({  }); container and after an ajax call I wanted the radio selected to change.

What sorted the issue was adding return true after the buttonset / button refresh.